# HttpContext.Current and ConcurrentDictionary

Tags: asp.net, .net, c#-4.0, concurrency, ihttphandler

Currently we have a very strange issue on our production server. For a specific param in query string, we get the data for query string in other request. I'm trying to figure out if this behavior can be caused, by the way I use ConcurrentDictionary in IHttpHandler:

Below is pseudo code example:

```
public class MyHandler : IHttpHandler
{
        private static ConcurrentDictionary<string, DataObject> _dataCache = new ConcurrentDictionary<string, DataObject>();

        public virtual bool IsReusable
        {
            get { return true; }
        }

        public virtual void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
        {
            Func<DataObject> getDataMethod = () =>
            {
                 return DataFactory.GetData(context.Request.QueryString["dataid"].ToLower());
            }

            string cacheKey = HttpUtility.UrlDecode(context.Request.QueryString["dataid"].ToLower());

            DataObject infoItem = _dataCache .GetOrAdd(cacheKey, (key) => { return getDataMethod(); })

            //Other processing code
        }
}
```

So it happens that for "`dataid=1`" i get the data for "`dataid=2`"...

When `getDataMethod` is executed, can I be sure that it will access the relevant `context`?

Comment: `_dataCache` is static which means it is common for all requests. As a result, the last request to write to a key wins. I doubt this is what you wanted to do.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos _dataCache is a static "cache" dictionary, so it should be the same for all request. The problem is sometimes, that for key=1 in dictionary inserted data of key=2.